# In Expo.io how can we specify the provisioning devices for ios Build?

Tags: ios, react-native, build, configuration, expo

I am trying to build an ipa file using expo.io - following the instructions is very easy - however, whenever I try to sync the file to a real device - an iPhone 7, it fails to install, providing the following message:

"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

I decided to open the ipa file and look for the embedded.mobileprovision file which should have the configuration necessary. I was surprised not to find anything at all in this file - there is no configuration such as:

```
   <key>ProvisionsAllDevices</key>
   <true>
```

or even

```
 <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
    <array>
        <string>caf2b03e4a4e1a80d9492c8bdcea0ea8df6a14a7</string>
        <string>1a5b7515ed0751d6de312f9520267f502b20eab0</string>
        <string>f4c368bb6c27119feb877e0d95d3891166ab48c8</string>
        <string>72234de7149e980a9e659e5417f764c47c5e7327</string>
    </array>
```

Therefore I am wondering - is there a configuration I am missing in my exp.json file? Should I change the file and "recompact it" in a zip/ipa format?

```
 {
  "name": "nonononnon",
  "description": "App for nononoon",
  "slug": "xxxxxxxx",
  "privacy": "public",
  "sdkVersion": "17.0.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "primaryColor": "#cccccc",
  "icon": "./assets/icons/xxxx_64x64.png",
  "notification": {
    "icon": "./assets/icons/xxx_64x64.png",
    "color": "#000000"
  },
  "loading": {
    "icon": "./assets/icons/xxxxxxx.png",
    "hideExponentText": false
  },
  "packagerOpts": {
    "assetExts": ["ttf"]
  },
  "ios": {
    "supportsTablet": false,
    "bundleIdentifier": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  "android":{
    "package": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your question i tried out installing my own expo app on my phone via xcode.

I got the same error.
It seems you cannot directly run the ipa on your phone. 
You will have to upload the ipa file to Itunes connect for review first and once it is approved only then can you submit it to the app store or test it on specific devices through the Test Flight App. 
You can use the application loader to upload it.

More on the application loader: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html